# Drupal print breaks when rendering a region

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I've come across a bit of a stumbling block with the

```
<?php print render ($page['pages_machine_name']); ?>
```

code in a Drupal site. 
The issue only started when moving from 7.33 to 7.36.

What happens is, rather than display the content of the page, which in this instance is a `<ul>`, it puts several wrapping `<div>`s and `<span>`s round the `<ul>` and it's content. This is fine, but what happens is, they render out with incomplete links and as such, break the rest of the page:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.co.uk&lt;div class=" field="" field-name-field-link-three-url="" field-type-text="" field-label-above"="">"&gt;
<div class="field field-name-field-link-three-name field-type-text field-label-above"><div class="field-label">Link Three | Name:&nbsp;</div><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">Our people</div></div></div></a>
```

As you can see, the end of the website's domain is marked up with a less than rather than an actual symbol and as such, breaks all the other tags that follow it. 

Does anyone know what could be causing this and what can be done to fix it? 
 Thanks in advance for any help you can provide :)

Comment: You can try using the php `strip_tags()` function to remove the `<div>` and `<span>` tags

Comment: There is a nice article here on using render arrays in drupal, ensure you are using it for the right reasons.-https://www.drupal.org/node/930760 also add more code on before an after that render statement to guage where and how you are using it.

Comment: There must be some structure problem try to debug $page array using dsm or similar functions of devel module. that might help you knowing what content you are rendering

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've dug in to the issue further and found that the issue resides in a node file. 

The <a> tag's URL is built by using a `<?php print render($content['field_link_one_url']); ?>` and that pulls in a all the divs around the content, as they are the label for the field. 

I now need a way to stop the field's Labels coming in. (Turning them to hidden in the Manage Display view does not work)

Comment: **Resolution found.**

When searching I found this page [link](http://thanhsiang.org/faqing/node/178) on which, the code offers the following solution: (Edited from 'filename' to 'value' to get get the text value inside the field)  `<?php print $node->field_name_goes_here['und']['0']['value']; ?>` 

This delivers exactly what I was looking for, in this case, just the content of the field. Hope this can help other in the future.

Comment: Incorrect link above, should be this [correct link](http://robotlikehuman.com/web/printing-cck-content-field-values-drupal-7)

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and mark it as answered. Seeing how you dug to your field, it should be noted, that – in Drupal 7 – there is a [more elegant way to programatically render fields](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way).

Comment: Thanks @Paracetamol, I'll look in to that link. I've also posted the resolution as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When searching I found this [page link](http://robotlikehuman.com/web/printing-cck-content-field-values-drupal-7) on which, the code offers the following solution: (Edited from 'filename' to 'value' to get get the text value inside the field) `<?php print $node->field_name_goes_here['und']['0']['value']; ?>` This delivers exactly what I was looking for, in this case, just the content of the field. Hope this can help other in the future.